# MacOSX Screensaver and CG.framework

Tags: macos, opengl, frameworks, screensaver, cg

I'm developing openGL-based screensaver for Mac (10.6), and have an issue with linking to CG.framework.

Once mentioned framework is linked to project, screensaver becomes to be invalid. No warning, no errors. Just grayed in list of screensavers.

UPDATE:

Way to reproduce is very simple, but you need CG.framework from NVidia:

1. Make an empty screensaver project in XCode
2. Compile and install it to verify that its OK
3. Add CG.framework and rebuild project
4. Try to install again. After that i got "You cannot use the "xxx" screen saver on this computer. Contact the developer of this screen saver for a newer version." message

Comment: Not sure about screensavers, but I was having issues with wxWidgets executables being unresponsive when run without an app bundle.  Does your screensaver have an app bundle?

Comment: have you tried running your app? does it run well?

Comment: without CG.framework screensaver runs well.